# How do I make elements stretch vertically or horizontally to the remaining height or width?

Tags: css, height, width, stretch

In my layout, I have a header that goes across the entire page.  Below that is a side navigation bar on the left side.  Then i have a content container to the right.  I would like the navigation bar to stretch down to the bottom of my page and the container to stretch all the way to the right.

How would I achieve this?

```
#navigation {
    background: url(img/navigation_bg.png) repeat-y;
    width: 322px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    float: left;
    overflow: auto;
    text-align: center;
}

#navigation ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

#navigation ul li {
    background: url(img/nav-item_bg.png) repeat-x;
    height: 53px;
    line-height: 53px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-right: 1px;
    border-top: 1px solid #000;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
}

#navigation ul li a:link, #navigation ul li a:visited, #navigation ul li a:active {
    color: #2a2a2a;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 12pt;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#navigation ul li a:hover {
    background: #3399cc;
    color: #66ccff;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 12pt;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 321px;
    height: 53px;
    display: block;
}

#content-wrapper {
    float: left
    margin: 25px 25px 0px 25px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you want something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/sHdTX/1/

Firstly you need to set your body and html to 100% height,

then you can use the calc CSS to set the height of the navbar

```
height: -webkit-calc(100% - 40px);
```

Calc will work in modern browsers, this is the only way I know off without using images and JS.

Comment: Actually calc(100% - 40px) works in all browsers.  webkit worked in chrome, but not firefox.

Comment: hi, did you see my fiddle? it works for me in firefox, too. let me know;)

Comment: I had originally accepted your answer, however, I realized that this only works until you need to scroll down the page.